# Best way to create a DIV Layout with an interrupted Middle Line

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code:

```
<div id="contentKeypoint"><h3>Keypoint</h3><span data-placeholder="keypointName" /></div>
<div id="contentInputs"><h3>Input(s)</h3><ul></ul></div>
<div id="contentInputGiver"><h3>Input Giver(s)</h3><ul></ul></div>
<div id="contentOutputs"><h3>Output(s)</h3><ul></ul></div>
<div id="contentOutputConsumer"><h3>Output Consumer(s)</h3><ul></ul></div>
<div id="contentResponsible"><h3>Responsible(s)</h3><ul></ul></div>
<div id="contentReviewer"><h3>Reviewer(s)</h3><ul></ul></div>
```

The 7 DIV-Elements are populated by a JQuery background service. Now i have to create the following layout-behaviour which seems to be difficult to me:

[image: Content: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 Icon: 8,9]

1.) The DIVs 1,2,3 should always have the same height according to the largest element in the row

2.) The DIVs 4,5,6,7 should always have the same height according to the largest element in the row

3.) The area (DIV?) 8 and 9 should plave an icon always in the middle of the whole height

4.) The middle line should always have the same baseline (the gap in the middle should be in the same place)

5.) The width of the whole construct should not affect the icons that interrupt the lines.

Can someone give me a hint how to manage this CSS problem the best way? How would you construct this?

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/schludi/Lxqf563j/

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Viira i have added it.

Comment: Did you consider using CSS grid or flexbox ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxqf563j/24/ added white line

Comment: Viira: That is a good beginning i guess the only question is how to get the vertical icon gap in the middle of each column

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: The problem with flex-box is that i do not know how to get the line in the middle and interrupt with the icons in div are 8 and 9. Or is it in this case best way to use a table with colspan?

Comment: CSS-Grid could get you started - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mGydyP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help. I guess the best way is to use CSS-Grid like mentioned by Paulie_D.

I did it now with tables and cellspan and rowspan (what wasn't my first intention):

https://jsfiddle.net/schludi/Lxqf563j/

```
<table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAlign">
      <div id="contentInputs"><h3>Input(s)</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div id="verticalIconLine1">
          &copy;
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="cellAlign">
      <div id="contentKeypoint"><h3>Keypoint</h3>
        Product requirements update
      </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div id="verticalIconLine2">
        &copy;
      </div>      
    </td>
    <td class="cellAlign">
      <div id="contentOutputs"><h3>Output(s)</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>    
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellAlign">
      <div id="contentInputGiver"><h3>Input Giver(s)</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellAlign">
      <div id="contentResponsible"><h3>Responsible(s)</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellAlign">      
      <div id="contentReviewer"><h3>Reviewer(s)</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
        </ul>
      </div>      
    </td>
    <td class="cellAlign">
      <div id="contentOutputConsumer"><h3>Output Consumer(s)</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
            <li>DDsdfkl lksdjf lksdj k</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```